# IBM Websphere War Deployment Is Slow

Tags: websphere, war, ear

We are deploying our application war [180 mb] to IBM Websphere admin 8.5.5.9. It takes around 30 min to deploy a war.

In Weblogic there is a option for deploying a war, that is we don't need deploy a war second time onwards, so we just replace the updated war in that path and it takes a war from that path second time. Like, Is there any option in websphere. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

This page [Options for accelerating application deployment](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0812_webcon/0812_webcon.html) gives you several options for accelerating deployments. Article is to big to quote it here.

As alternative you can also do [partial updates](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_rapp_update.html) if you only need to change several files.